# How to delete item from Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a simple todo in react and I want to remove the selected task in todo. But when I run this code and try to delete any task, it gives an error:

> firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined"

```
componentWillMount: function() {
        this.firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://simpletodosapp.firebaseio.com/todos');
        var that = this;
        this.firebaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot){

            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var todos = data.val();
                todos['key'] = data.key;
                that.setState({tasks: todos})
            })
        });
    },

  handleTodo: function(text) {
        var newTask  = this.state.tasks.concat(text)
        this.firebaseRef.push(newTask)
       this.setState({tasks: newTask})

    },

    handleDelete: function(task_id, key) {
        this.firebaseRef.child(key).remove();
        var remove = this.state.tasks.splice(task_id, 1);
        this.setState({itasks: remove})

    },
```

Comment: Are you passing the correct name() in the this.firebaseRe.child() ?Use console debugging to check

Comment: What is the value of the key you are passing to your handleDelete function?